# How to prevent sliding with rigid bodies in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies, physics-engine

So, I am using Unity's Rigid body physics engine. And I made the player using a capsule collider. And after creating another rigid body with a Box collider I tried to jump onto it, only, the player starts to ever so slightly slide on top of it until eventually sliding off.

I want to be able to make the player jump onto movable objects without sliding on top unless there is enough of a slope to make sense for the player to slide off of. Is this possible, or does Unity's physics engine prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by applying a [Physic Material](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) to the player's capsule collider. Specifically, take a look at the **Dynamic Friction** and the **Static Friction** of the Physic Material. You may also want to set the **Friction Combine** to Maximum, if you want to ensure your player has a good grip on the platform regardless of what kind they land on.

A higher Dynamic Friction will quickly stop your player object if it starts sliding, while a higher Static Friction will make it harder for the player object to start sliding if it is otherwise stationary.

There isn't an exact science behind choosing these values; you'll really have to play around with it to see what feels right for your game.